# How can I put text in squares?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How can I put text in squares?

Please see 
my code:

```
\definecolor{MainRed}{rgb}{.6, .1, .1}

    \def\bigrectangle{(-7,-1) rectangle (6.5,4.7)}
\def\firstrectangle{(-9,0) rectangle (-5,4)}
\def\secondrectangle{(-4,0) rectangle (0,4)}
\def\thirdrectangle{(1,0) rectangle (5,4)}
\def\fourthrectangle{(6,0) rectangle (10,4)}
\def\firsttriangle{(4.5,4.1)--(7,4)--(4.5,8)--cycle}
\def\secondtriangle{(4.5,0)--(7.1,0)--(4.5,-4)--cycle}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
    \draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed!10]\bigrectangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed!10]\firsttriangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed!10]\secondtriangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed,rounded corners]\firstrectangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed,rounded corners]\secondrectangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed,rounded corners]\thirdrectangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed,rounded corners]\fourthrectangle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of drawing rectangles, define a node like:

```
\tikzset{mynode/.style={fill= MainRed,rounded corners,minimum 
                  size=2cm,text width=2cm,text=white,align=center}
    }
```

and use it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{MainRed}{rgb}{.6, .1, .1}

\def\bigrectangle{(-7,-1) rectangle (6.5,4.7)}
\def\firsttriangle{(4.5,4.1)--(7,4)--(4.5,8)--cycle}
\def\secondtriangle{(4.5,0)--(7.1,0)--(4.5,-4)--cycle}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={fill= MainRed,rounded corners,minimum size=2cm,text width=2cm,text=white,align=center}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed!10]\bigrectangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed!10]\firsttriangle;
\draw[fill= MainRed,color =MainRed!10]\secondtriangle;
\node[mynode] at (-7,2) {my text comes here};
\node[mynode] at (-2,2) {my text comes here};
\node[mynode] at (3,2) {my text comes here};
\node[mynode] at (8,2) {my text comes here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make use of an arrow instead of drawing those triangles:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{MainRed}{rgb}{.6, .1, .1}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={fill= MainRed,rounded corners,minimum size=2cm,text width=2cm,text=white,align=center}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.5]
\draw [line width=3cm,MainRed!10,arrows = {-Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=90:4cm, length=2cm]}] (-7,2) -- (8,2);
\node[mynode] at (-7,2) {my text comes here};
\node[mynode] at (-2,2) {my text comes here};
\node[mynode] at (3,2) {my text comes here};
\node[mynode] at (8,2) {my text comes here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I have a long text dimensions of squares will be changed not at the same size !

Comment: @Haouam: For such cases, ditch `minimum size` and use `minimum height` and `minimum width` separately. You may also need `text width`. Play with these until you get desired results.  For example: `\node[mynode,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=4cm,text width=4cm] at (-9,2) {my text comes here};`.